# How do I map one models objects to another models objects in a view

Tags: django, django-views

I have a bunch of message records that I would like to assign to different taskboxes.

```
#models.py

class TaskBox(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)

    class Admin:
        pass

class InboxEntry(models.Model):
    job_number = models.CharField(max_length=14, unique=False, blank=False, null=False)
    job_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=False, null=False)
    request = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=PRINT_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    date_due = models.DateTimeField(("Due"),auto_now=False)
    note = models.TextField(max_length=1000, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    assigned_by = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, blank=False, null=False)
    box = models.ForeignKey(TaskBox)
    assigned_to = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, related_name='name', blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default="Awaiting Action")

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.job_number, self.job_name)

    class Admin: 
        pass

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['status']
```

The idea is for the template to have some generic tags like {{ for taskbox in taskboxes }} to create a separate div for each taskbox that will hold a table for that box's records. My problem is constructing the view function...

```
#views.py

def display_prdInboxEntry(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PrdInboxForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('taskmanager/display/'+ id +'/')
        else:
            form = PrdInboxForm(request.POST)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('taskmanager/display/'+ id +'/')

    else:
        form = PrdInboxForm()
        user = request.user
        **taskboxes = TaskBox.objects.all()
        records_1 = InboxEntry.objects.filter(taskboxes[id]=1)
        records_2 = InboxEntry.objects.filter(taskboxes[id]=2)
        records_3 = InboxEntry.objects.filter(taskboxes[id]=3)
        ..... **

        return render_to_response('taskmanager/taskmanager_view.html', {'form': form, 'taskboxes': taskboxes, 'records_1' : records_1, 'records_2' : records_2, 'records_3' : records_3, 'user': user}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The InboxEntry model has a field called "box" that's just a reference to the TaskBox model. I need a way to map say... TaskBox id 1 with all of the InboxEntry objects with "box = 1" so that I can populate the templates appropriately. Can I construct the function to accommodate this, or am I going about it the wrong way entirely?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the automatically-generated attribute for reverse lookups. You can get a `QuerySet` of all `InboxEntries` associated with a `TaskBox` like this:

```
TaskBox.objects.filter(id=1).inboxentry_set.all()
```

See the [documentation on related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects).

Comment: returns a TaskBox object that is not iterable in template, as opposed to a queryset of entries related to a specific taskbox.

Comment: @kjarsenal: My mistake, `inboxentry_set` is the `Manager`, not the `QuerySet`. So you can filter on it, etc. Just use `all()` if you want them all.