# accessing list or dictionary values for use in view function

Tags: django, django-views

Let's say I used a loop to generate either a list or dictionary of variables:

```
a = {}
b = []
k = 1
count = TaskBox.objects.all().count()
output = ""
while k <= count:
    ck = str(k)
    newline = output.join("box"+ck+" = InboxEntry.objects.filter(box="+ck+")")
    c.append(newline)
    b['box'+ck] = "InboxEntry.objects.filter(box="+ck+")"
    k += 1
```

yielding: ['box1 = InboxEntry.objects.filter(box=1)', 'box2 = InboxEntry.objects.filter(box=2)']

and 
{'box2': 'InboxEntry.objects.filter(box=2)', 'box1': 'InboxEntry.objects.filter(box=1)'}

how do I unpack the variables from either structure for use in views.py?

I'm ultimately looking for something like:

```
def display_prdInboxEntry(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PrdInboxForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('taskmanager/display/'+ id +'/')
        else:
            form = PrdInboxForm(request.POST)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('taskmanager/display/'+ id +'/')

    else:
        form = PrdInboxForm()
        user = request.user
        u = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=id)
        boxrecords = TaskBox.objects.all()
        assignedrecords = InboxEntry.objects.filter(assigned_by=u)

        '''loop code'''
        a = {}
        b = []
        k = 1
        count = TaskBox.objects.all().count()
        output = ""
        while k <= count:
            ck = str(k)
            newline = output.join("box"+ck+" =  InboxEntry.objects.filter(box="+ck+")")
            c.append(newline)
            b['box'+ck] = "InboxEntry.objects.filter(box="+ck+")"
            k += 1

        '''need to pull these values from the product of the loop'''
        box1 = InboxEntry.objects.filter(box=1)
        box2 = InboxEntry.objects.filter(box=2)

        records = InboxEntry.objects.filter(assigned_to=u).order_by('status')
        return render_to_response('taskmanager/taskmanager_view.html', {'form': form, 'assignedrecords': assignedrecords, 'records': records, 'boxrecords': boxrecords, 'box1' : box1, 'box2' : box2, 'user': user}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. Why can't you use the second version?

Comment: in the second version, the box1 and box2 variables have already been extracted from the loop generator. By using a loop, I can generate a list (or dictionary) of variables - I just don't know how to extract them so they appear as they do in the second version.

Comment: The number of TaskBox objects is determined by the end user so I can't predetermine the number of box variables.

Comment: Just append the values to a list. I don't see why you need all that stuff with the text representation of the query.

Comment: I have a list:  ['box1 = InboxEntry.objects.filter(box=1)', 'box2 = InboxEntry.objects.filter(box=2)']. The variables I need are represented as strings in that list. I don't know how to get the variables out of the list. That's the crux of the question.

Comment: But why have you put things in the list in that format in the first place? That's what I don't understand. This is clearly an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: re. xy, you may be right. Am working on a solution to a problem I posed <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30447964/how-do-i-map-one-models-objects-to-another-models-objects-in-a-view">here</a>. Thanks for trying to help. For now, I'll just go back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so I didn't need to "extract" the variables from the dictionary in order to make use of them. I simply put a loop in my view code to generate the dictionary of variables, and then concatenated that dictionary with my http response dictionary:

```
def display_prdInboxEntry(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':

    '''form code'''

    else:
        form = PrdInboxForm()
        user = request.user
        u = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=id)
        assignedrecords = InboxEntry.objects.filter(assigned_by=u)
        records = InboxEntry.objects.filter(assigned_to=u).order_by('status')
        boxrecords = TaskBox.objects.all()
        boxes = TaskBox.objects.all().count()

        ''' variable generator'''
        boxdict = {}
        for x in range(1, boxes + 1):
            boxdict['box{0}s'.format(x)] = InboxEntry.objects.filter(box='{0}'.format(x))


        returndict = {'form': form, 'assignedrecords': assignedrecords, 'records': records, 'boxrecords': boxrecords, 'user': user}

        ''' return dictionary concatenation'''
        z = returndict.copy()
        z.update(boxdict)
        return render_to_response('taskmanager/taskmanager_view.html', z, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Don't know how conventional it is, and it will be something of a challenge to code the template efficiently - but it works, and allows users to create taskboxes on-the-fly in admin, without having to adapt the view code - which is what I was after.